# permission issue on powerautomate flows . Accessing user not part of bookings calendar

Tags: triggers, calendar, power-automate, booking.com-api

[image]I have been getting permission issues on power automated flows, in account

Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="Invalid authority. Accessing user not part of bookings calendar")

I can access the Booking Page …

and on the Booking Page, My user is also showing as an Administrator

tried to troubleshoot it, but it seems it can be done on the admin center for which I don't have access

I am using Trigger , 'when appointment is created'
and connection I am using is of Microsoft Booking Preview connection

shared screenshot ..

I tried to add co owner , but it still not working

Comment: Update your question with more details on which action/connector you are using, how the flow is triggered, and which identity is being using for the connector. Share a screen snip of the relevant part of the flow, if it helps.

Comment: I shared, some personal credentials I cannot shared